# Is there a way to test if a firewal (AFwall) l is blocking a specific app?

Tags: keyboard, internet, firewall

I installed AFwall+ to block internet connection for my keyboard. Is there a way I can test if this is actually working? The keyboard is Swifkey.

Comment: Try to load themes in that keyboard. It wouldn't be able to fetch new ones from server.

Answer (score 0):

Android setting has an option named 'Data Usage' where you can see per app data consumption. Compare consumed data on two instances to make sure it is not using any Internet.

PS: IMO If you've Xposed installed then LighteningWall could be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

1) In AFWall+ go to Menu -> Preferences -> Log -> Turn on log service

2) Open your keyboard and do something requiring internet connection

3) Return to AFWall+ and open Menu -> View log and you'll see it was blocked